# MongoDB query array where all elements match criteria

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I hava a collection of 3 documents:

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"gender":"male"},{"id:1,"gender":"male"},{"id":1,"gender":"male"}]}
{"users":[{"id":1,"gender":"male"},{"id:1","gender":"male"},{"id":1,"gender":"female"}]}
{"users":[{"id":1,"gender":"female"},{"id":1,"gender":"female"},{"id":1,"gender":"female"}]}
```

I want to write a query where every gender is male (users.gender:"male") and as a result to get only:

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"gender":"male"},{"id:1,"gender":"male"},{"id":1,"gender":"male"}]}
```

So far I was able to get those documents where at least one field matches criteria. So I was getting:

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"gender":"male"},{"id:1","gender":"male"},{"id":1,"gender":"female"}]}
{"users":[{"id":1,"gender":"female"},{"id":1,"gender":"female"},{"id":1,"gender":"female"}]}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: please rephrase the question. that is not valid json, and the example doesn't make sense.

Comment: The documents are not in proper json.Can you please edit your question to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only two type of genders in your documents : `male` and `female`, all the documents which do not contain `female` as the gender type, will automatically be those with every gender type as `male`. Hence `$nin` [[**doc**]](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) can be used.

Of course, this is heavily assuming and inferring from your example, which is not clear at all. Please format your question to be correct and concise so that others can benefit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually another way of saying what Abhishek Pathak already said:

You can exclude `female` from the possible set of results. Assuming your collection is called `example` you can use the following query:

```
db.examples.find({"users.gender" : {$nin: ["female"]}})
```